# Extracting URLs from a list of strings

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, regular-expressions

If I have a list of strings:

```
list = {"my element 1 http://link.com", "http://link2.com my element 2"}
```

then how do I extract a list of the valid URL links from each string?

Something like

```
StringCases[list, "http" ~~ _]
```

probably but I wasn't able to know how to end my pattern.

Comment: Yet another way, `Select[StringSplit[#], StringMatchQ[#, "http://*"] &] & /@ list`.  Sorry about the nested `Function`.

Comment: @Szabolcs go answer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way:

```
StringCases[list, "http://" ~~ Except[WhitespaceCharacter] ..]
```

> `{{"http://link.com"}, {"http://link2.com"}}`

Comment: that's great but I don't see what the pattern ".." does in the documentation?

Comment: @su1 Look up [`Repeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Repeated.html), a good friend on many a jolly pattern matching occasion :-)

Answer (score 6):

Another way, similar to @YvesKlett, but with `RegularExpression`.

```
StringCases[list, RegularExpression["http://\\S+"]]
```

> {{"http://link.com"}, {"http://link2.com"}}

In `RegularsExpression` \\S means non space characters. You can find more information in Wolfram documentations [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/RegularExpressions.html)

Comment: You could give a short description of your regex to make it even more educational ;-)

Comment: @YvesKlett Agree. Done!

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
list = {"my element 1 http://link.com", 
  "http://link2.com my element 2"}

TextCases[#, "URL"] & /@ list
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \text{http://link.com} \\
 \text{http://link2.com} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: For more discussion on valid domain names, follow the [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21172095/grep-valid-domain-regex). Here I have assumed that `TextCases` goes through rigorous checks and delivers correct results.